# Lorentz contraction in the special theory of relativity and physical effects

Tags: special-relativity

I'm wondering about the physical meaning of Lorentz contraction within the scope of the special theory of relativity since there're several "real" effects that are supposed to happen due to it e.g. string braking in Bell's spaceship paradox. If we take a look at the [derrivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction#Known_proper_length) of Lorentz contraction, we clearly see it only relies on the invariance of the speed of light. This suggests that the contraction is not caused by some "physical" forces or space effects (like what we see in GR), but rather it is caused by the time when we register light. If so, how can it explain any "real" effect like string breaking?